# CSS background Image plus gradient in 4 corners

Tags: css, gradient, background-image

What I want to achieve is something like this

[image]

What I tried so far is the CSS3 multiple background, it worked when I used one corner

See it here: [CSS code](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+30&0.65+0,0+30;Custom)

But it didn't work when I added more 'backgrounds'

See example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhLsQ/3/)

```
code is too long to post it here, view it on jsfiddle
```

Is there any suggestion to improve this, or is there a better way to doit? 
Thank you

Update: Answer

Here is the background (gradient) I used. [Link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+58,000000+100&0+55,0.8+100;Custom)

And here is how I used the code:

HTML

```
<section class="window">
   <div class="win1con">

   </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
    .window {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .win1con {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 0%;
      /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
      background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 55%, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 58%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(55%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(58%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
      background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%); /* IE10+ */
      background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 55%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 58%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%); /* W3C */
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#cc000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
      top: 0%;
      background: url('../images/vntg.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use box-shadow:

```
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/7TX9BQU.jpg?1?9512');
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 10px #000;
```

The key to make this work is the 'inset' value. Tt makes the shadow appear on the inside of the element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhLsQ/5/

info about box-shadow: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: Your idea is good, but it isn't exactly what I am looking for, Your example looks more like a square, and it would be better if it looks circular. But I think I'll go with it.. If there is another idea, It'd be good to see it.

Comment: Then you may be looking more for a radial gradient. http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/

Comment: I think that's the way around it... to apply inner radial shadow for an inner div...